# Check for duplication before insertion

Tags: php, sql, insert, duplicates

**Problem**

I have a table `tbl_student_courses` which join 2 tables `student` and `courses` now when data is inserted it is the combination of 2 ids `course_id` and `student_id`. I just want there would be no duplication of this combination in `tbl_student_courses`.

**Code**

```
foreach($_POST['sel_course'] as $val) {

$query_std_course = "
  INSERT INTO
    `tbl_student_courses`
  SET
    `course_id` = '".$val."',
    `std_id` = '".$_POST['std']."',
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM `tbl_student_courses` WHERE course_id=$val AND std_id=$std
  )";

}
```

**Help**

This query giving `SQL` syntax error.

Can any body help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are missing quotes in the inner query

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are missing quotes one inner query values.
You `SQL` query should look like this

```
$sql = "
  INSERT INTO
    `tbl_student_courses`
  SET
    `course_id` = '".$val."',
    `std_id` = '".$_POST['std']."',
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM `tbl_student_courses` WHERE course_id='".$val."' AND std_id='".$std."'
  )";
```

**NOTE:** Inserting in database not prepared statements like `std_id = '".$_POST['std']."'` is not of a good manner. Consider using `PDO` or **`filter`** data yourself, bec. this can be easily used for `SQL Iinjection` therefore it is potential security breach.

**UPDATE:** Try to use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` or `INSERT IGNORE INTO table`.

You can find more information regarding your implementation - http://bogdan.org.ua/2007/10/18/mysql-insert-if-not-exists-syntax.html

And read about proposed implementation - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 0):

The SQL syntax you seek is the `MERGE` statement, or its equivalent on your platform

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(SQL)